# Unique extension of states (when there is a conditional expectation involved)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $0\ne\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{A}$ be a $C^*$-subalgebra and assume that $\mathcal{A}$ is unital. Suppose that there exists a conditional expectation $$\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{B}}:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}.$$

Further assume that every state on $\mathcal{B}$ extends uniquely to a state on $\mathcal{A}$ (e.g., when $\mathcal{B}$ is a hereditary subalgebra). Is it the case then that every state on $\mathcal{A}$ factorizes through $\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{B}}$?

For any state $\varphi$ on $\mathcal{B}$, let us denote its extension to $\mathcal{A}$ by $\bar{\varphi}$. Say that $\psi$ is a state on $\mathcal{A}$. Then, $\psi|_{\mathcal{B}}$ is a state on $\mathcal{B}$.

By assumption of unique extension,
$\bar{\psi_{\mathcal{B}}}=\psi_{\mathcal{B}}\circ\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{B}}$.

On the other hand, $\psi$ itself is an extension of $\psi_{\mathcal{B}}$. So, $$\psi=\bar{\psi_{\mathcal{B}}}=\psi_{\mathcal{B}}\circ\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{B}}$$

Is this alright? The question comes down to whether $\psi$ itself can be considered as an extension of $\psi|_{\mathcal{B}}$ or not?

This is where I am confused at. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does $B$ contain the unit of $A$?

Comment: Here is a trivial counter-example: what if $A\ne0$, $B=0$, conditional expectation is the $0$ map; if every state on $A$ factorized, then every state would be $0$, a contradiction

Comment: $\mathcal{B}$ contains the unit of $\mathcal{A}$

Comment: Then your argument is alright.

Comment: Will the argument go through If $\mathcal{B}$ has an approximate identity instead of being unital?

Comment: Every $C^*$-algebra has an approximate unit. If you mean that $B$ has an approximate unit FOR $A$, then yes.

Comment: I wanted to know if in your example, I take $B$ to be a non-zero $C^*$-algebra, then whether the argument will go through or not. Why do we require $B$ to have an approximate unit for $A$? Where does the argument fail?

Comment: Take for example $A=\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}$ and $B=\mathbb{C}\oplus0$. Every state on $B$ extends uniquely to a state on $A$, but not all states factorize through the expectation $(z,w)\mapsto z$.