# Extension of states on $C^*$-algebras (unique extension compared to a sub algebra)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

The following question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4709222/unique-extension-of-states-when-there-is-a-conditional-expectation-involved), which was asked earlier on the forum. I am still a bit confused by the situation and decided to ask a separate question about it.

Let $C\subset B\subset A$ be an inclusion of $C^*$-algebras with $1_{A}=1_{B}$.

Assume that $C$ is a non-zero hereditary $C^*$-sub-algebra of $A$. Moreover, there is a conditional expectation $E_B:A\to B$.

Question: Is it true that every state on $B$ extends uniquely to a state on $A$?

Since, $C$ is a hereditary $C^*$-sub-algebra of $A$, every state on $C$ extends uniquely to a state on $A$. Now, given a state $\tau$ on $B$, $\tau_e^1$ and $\tau_e^2$ be any two possible extensions of $\tau$ to $A$. Now, $$\tau_e^1|_C=\tau_e^2|_C,$$
and hence, by the unique-extension property of $C$ inside $A$, they must agree. Moreover, $\tau\circ E_B$ is also one possible extension of $\tau$. So, this is the only possible extension.

Is this alright?

Comment: Why is $C$ even considered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not true.

Consider$\def\CC{\mathbb C}$
$$
A=M_2(\CC),\qquad B=\Big\{\begin{bmatrix} a&0\\0&d\end{bmatrix}:\ a,d\in\CC\Big\},\qquad
C=\Big\{\begin{bmatrix} a&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}:\ a\in\CC\Big\}.
$$
Then $C$ is hereditary (both in $A$ and in $B$) and $B\subset A$ with the same unit.

Consider the normalized trace on $B$,
$$
\varphi\Big(\begin{bmatrix} a&0\\0&d\end{bmatrix}\Big)=\frac{a+d}2,
$$
and the two extensions to $A$
$$
\psi_1\Big(\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\Big)=\frac{a+d}2,\qquad\qquad\psi_2\Big(\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\Big)=\frac{a+b+c+d}2.
$$
Where your argument fails is that the restriction of a state to a subalgebra is not necessarily a state. So every state in $C$ admits a unique extension, but $B$ has states (as in the example) that do not restrict to states of $C$.

Comment: Is the restriction of a state on the bidual $\mathcal{A}^{**}$ to a map on $\mathcal{A}$ a state because the identities coincide?

Comment: If the subalgebra has the same unit, every state restricts to a state. Straightforward consequence of the fact that positivity of a linear functional is characterized by achieving its norm at the identity.

Comment: Lovely. Thought so much.